# Office 365 'Create Event' Rest API is giving error

Tags: node.js, office365

I am new user on stackoverflow as well as in office 365 development using node.js.

I am successfully getting User(my own office 365 account) mails,calendar events using this tutorial (https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/node)

but when i am trying to Create an Event in my calender it gives me below error
"{"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."}}"

Please provide me suggestions on the same.

Below is the code for creating event which i copied from [https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations#CreateEvents] here

```
    function createEvent(response, request) {
var cookieName = 'node-tutorial-token';
   var cookie = request.headers.cookie;
//    if (cookie && cookie.indexOf(cookieName) !== -1) {
        console.log("Cookie: ", cookie);
        // Found our token, extract it from the cookie value
        var start = cookie.indexOf(cookieName) + cookieName.length + 1;
        var end = cookie.indexOf(';', start);
        end = end === -1 ? cookie.length : end;
        var token = cookie.substring(start, end);
        console.log("Token found in cookie: " + token);

var event = new outlook.Microsoft.OutlookServices.Event();
event.subject = 'Your Subject';
event.start = new Date("October 30, 2014 11:13:00").toISOString();
event.end = new Date("October 30, 2014 12:13:00").toISOString();

// Body
event.body = new outlook.Microsoft.OutlookServices.ItemBody();
event.body.content = 'Body Content';
event.body.contentType = outlook.Microsoft.OutlookServices.BodyType.Text;

// Location
event.location = new outlook.Microsoft.OutlookServices.Location();
event.location.displayName = 'Location';

// Attendee
var attendee1 = new outlook.Microsoft.OutlookServices.Attendee();
var emailAddress1 = new outlook.Microsoft.OutlookServices.EmailAddress();
emailAddress1.name = "abc";
emailAddress1.address = "abc@abcdt.onmicrosoft.com";

attendee1.emailAddress = emailAddress1;

event.attendees.push(attendee1);
 var outlookClient = new outlook.Microsoft.OutlookServices.Client('https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0', 
       authHelper.getAccessTokenFn(token));

outlookClient.me.calendar.events.addEvent(event)
    .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response._Id);
}, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
```

});

}

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show you code.

Comment: Have you requested for calendar.readwrite permission for your app?

Comment: @UweAllner i have updated my question with code.

Comment: @VenkatAyyadevara-MSFT i tried to give delegate permission to my self from outlook but it says "you can not add your self in the delegate permission user".

Comment: You don't need to add yourself as a delegate in Outlook.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your app has requested for calendar.readwrite permission and you need this to create new events.  In the example you followed, your app registered for only Calendar.Read permissions (see below).  [image: Your app requested Calendar.Read permission]

You should instead go to https://dev.outlook.com/AppRegistration to register an app with Calendar.ReadWrite permission which is required to create new events.[image: Request Calendar.ReadWrite permission]

Comment: It is working now! Thank you so much @Venkat. I have one more question regarding create event, as using above code i am able to create event in my own office 365 account, but i want to create event to other user's office account in my organization, can you please suggest me what steps i need to take.

Comment: Accessing other users calendars isn't yet supported using the REST APIs, but we are working to add this support.  I don't have a timeline to share for that.

Comment: Okay @Venkat Ayyadevara - MSFT, Other then REST APIs is their any way to create events in other user's office 365 account within same organization as i read this article [blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/… and somehow it matches my requirement, can you please suggest me on this.

Comment: You can use Exchange Web Services.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn495611(v=exchg.150).aspx